# How to open another activity with the desired screen orientation?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to preview PDF file, but run viewer in a landscape fixed mode.
Here is my current source code:

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Is there a way to say it should view it in landscape mode ?
Thanks in advance!

**EIDT:** PDF viewer is 3rd party app

Comment: You cannot do it unless the third-party app supports it, probably id doesn't. If it do you'll have to set a specific param in the intent's bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell the user to turn their phone.

Each application determines on its own how to handle screen orientation. You have no ability to override how other applications behave, any more than they have the ability to override how you behave.

**EDIT:** To clarify, this assumes that you are trying to open a third-party PDF viewer. @Kurru's answer is correct for activities of your own that you write.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by setting in your manifest on the activity you want to be in landscape mode

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

This only works for Activities you control

Comment: That only works if he writes the activity in question. From the code snippet, it would appear that the OP is trying to open a third-party PDF viewer.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I just noticed this after submitted my answer and so added that detail

Comment: My intent indeed runs a 3rd party app installed on a device. Thanks for this detail